# program to print the word starting with first character

Tags: c

This code should print the word starting with input character but something wrong with it.

I have already checked by using `fflush(stdin)`

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char str;
    int n,in;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(in=0;in<n;in++){  
        scanf("%c",&str);
        for(in=0;in<n;in++){
            if((str=='b')||(str=='B'))
                printf("Battleship");
            else if((str=='c')||(str=='C'))
                printf("Cruiser");
            else if((str=='d')||(str=='D'))
                printf("Destroyer");
            else
                printf("Fringate"); 
        }
   }
}
```

When I am providing test case, it is not taking input and getting out of the program.

Comment: Give the white space before `%c` to consume the newline character from the input, `scanf(" %c",&str);` And you intended to put `scanf()` inside loop ? else `str` will always same for `n` iteration

Comment: the second loop is not running and it is automatically printing the prevous output

Comment: why is that so since i have provided scanf it should scan inside the loop before printing the output

Comment: ok i got the solution thank you

Comment: My bad, I didn;t see that.

Comment: Use differenet variable in second loop, instead of 'in', use some other name

Comment: why should i give whitespace,please give me the reason for that ,i didnt get the logic to do that

Comment: You need `" %c"` because [`scanf()` leaves the newline in the input buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer).  You should be cautious about [Using `fflush(stdin)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin); it doesn't work everywhere.  You should be testing the return value of `scanf()` every time you call it so you can spot EOF and other problems reliably.

Comment: Also, in English the ship type is "frigate" not "fringate".  And don't you have some squares that have no vessel in them?  At the moment, you have frigates everywhere you don't have a bigger vessel.